# Is there an Empty String field in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to get an empty string but I think `var str = ""` is not as good as `String str = String.Empty;` in C# in term of readability.

I had browsed `NSString` documentation and found no such thing in it. Is there a similar field in iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a String.empty in Swift. But you can initialize a new `String` which is also empty:

```
var emptyString = String()
```

But you can write a .empty method by yourself by using the `extension` possilibility Swift provides. (Even if it's overkill and not necessary at all, you've got the tools to do it :-) ):

```
extension String{
 static func emptyString()->String{
     return String()     

 }
}
```

Comment: Your `empty()` method does not compile (missing return type). One probably would make that a *static* method (or property).

Comment: Sorry, I've written that without IDE.

Comment: Do you thing it is good to write `var str = ""` or the way I am trying to do OR just the matter of style. Learning programming now any suggestion is good.

Comment: Me personally would use `var str  = "" ` because it's more clear in my opinion.